# Can't connect to mysql database C#

Tags: c#, mysql, serial-port

I am trying to connect to my db with C# and query some data.

But i get this error when trying to connect:

```
{"Fatal error encountered during command execution."}
{"Parameter '?param1' must be defined."}
```

Code:

```
checkmsisdn.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM acl where msisdn = ?param1 and passwd = ?param2 and items LIKE (\"%?param3%\")";  //fourth
//try
//{
    sqlConn.Open();
    Reader = checkmsisdn.ExecuteReader();
    checkmsisdn.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("param1", msisdn));
    checkmsisdn.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("param2", passwd));
    checkmsisdn.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("param3", itemno));
//}
//catch 
//{ 
//    Console.WriteLine("Error Connecting to Database\n"); 
//}

while (Reader.Read())
{
    name = (Reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
}
```

the query will return only one line, the name. 
am i using the parameters correctly for this query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `ExecuteReader()` before adding the parameters.

Comment: now i am getting this when i ran it for the second time:
Parameter 'param1' has already been defined.

Comment: checkmsisdn.Parameters.Clear(); this did it ! :D